# Design Pattern for Data Structure

Tags: c++, design-patterns, iterator

This question has been answered, so what follows below is an explanation of what I wanted to achieve.

I wanted to create a tablular data structure designed to allow efficient access to any row entry through a primary column that could possibly be hashed. I thought that the best way to go about this would be to maintain a vector of doubly-linked lists, each of which would represent one column, and a map that would contain mappings of primary column entry hashes to nodes. Now, the first mistake I made is in thinking that I would need to create my own implementation of a doubly-linked list in order to be able to store pointers to nodes, when in fact the standard states that iterators to std::list do not get invalidated as a result of insertion or splicing (see larsmans's answer). Here's some pseudocode to illustrate what I wanted to do previously. Assume the existence of a typename T representing the entry type and the existence of a dlist and node class, as described previously.

```
typedef dlist<T> column_type;
typedef vector<T> row_type;
typedef ptr_unordered_map<int32_t, row_type> hash_type;

shared_ptr<ptr_vector<column_type> > columns;
shared_ptr<hash_type> hashes;
```

Now, after reading larsmans's answer, I learned that I wouldn't need any of this since Boost.MultiIndex fulfills all of my needs as it is. Even if I did, Boost.Intrusive offers more efficient data structures to accomplish what I describe.

Thanks to all who took interest in the question or offered help! If you have any more questions, add another comment and I'll do my best to clarify the question further.

Comment: `Operator[]` should be allowed only on if the underlying is contiguous memory sequence. Using that on a linked list like data structure is not a good idea IMO. That is the reason why on `std::list`, `operator[]` isn't overloaded while on `std::vector` it is.

Comment: @Mahesh - since when `std::map` is contiguous?  `Operator[]` should be allowed only if the data structure supports identifiers to stored data, which `vector` and `map` do, but `list` doesn't.

Comment: How is this different from a `std::list`? Iterators are functionally equivalent to node pointers in a doubly-linked list. -- gives you the previous node, ++ give you the next node, and * gives you the value. `std::list` iterators only are invalidated when the list is destroyed or that particular item is deleted from the list. What exactly do you intend to gain by doing this?

Comment: "I recently found that I would have to implement a doubly-linked list in C++". Purely as an educational exercise? I'd like to read the justification for putting your own implementation into production code otherwise!

Comment: For those who are interested as to why I'd want to do this, please refer to the edit. Also, sorry I had a brainfart: I forgot that I was talking about a list and not a vector, so I do not plan to have the structure support operator[].

Comment: @littleadv, `list` could support identifiers (the index of the element like `vector`) to its contents very well. `list` doesn't have a `[]` operator because it is not relevant for that particular structure: its performance would be bad (in `O(n)`).

Comment: @J.N. *could* is a very bad choice of a word. *Does* would be better, but it **doesn't**. `list` **DOESN'T** support access by identifier, as defined in the C++ standard, and in any reasonable implementation of a linked list. Random access in linked list as you said cannot be implemented, so it's just pointless. *Could* you implement a pointless operation? Sure. *Should* you? no.

Comment: @littleadv, please don't invent things that are not in the standard: "access by identifier" is something that doesn't appear in my copy of N3242. You mean "random access". Then, inefficient is not pointless. Providing a slow solution in a standard library would be a mistake since beginners would abuse the functionality. On the other hand as projects go, I can very well imagine that one day you'll want to access an element at a given position in a list and be ready to pay the performance price for it.

Comment: @J.N. in all my years of experience that yet to have happened to me. I feel sorry for you if you had to access linked lists by position, that suggest a really poor data structure design.

Comment: @void-pointer: Even after your edit, @Nicol Bolas' questions stays valid. Why can't you work with a std::list<>, with iterators, begin(), end(), and so forth? This is functionally equivalent to what you want.

Comment: @phresnel I'm a little confused about how this would work. If you read the edit in my post I describe the hash structure that maps key hashes to nodes in the DLLs. Assuming I have a node to iterator map, any addition of rows may cause entries in the map to become outdated.

Comment: I added another edit for purposes of clarification.

Comment: 0) The last edit was 3 hours ago. 1) there is no mention of DLLs in your question. 2) now are talking maps or lists?

Comment: 3) you shouldn't write "I edited the question" when the edit is in the future.

Comment: @phresnel I mentioned that "I'm creating a tabular structure that will be backed by a vector of doubly-linked lists." in my first edit; sorry for the confusion. We're talking about lists, but the reason for which I want to implement the list I describe involves maps. It's strange that the second edit does not show up for you yet; perhaps try refreshing?

Comment: Okay, I am really confused now. Maybe add some pseudo-code. Do you need to keep your hash-into-list nodes valid or just the list nodes? Really, I am confused. Edit: You should be more precise on the terminology. C++ has distinct containers named exactly `map`, `vector`, `list` (which IS a doubly linked list), some non-standard extensions (but to appear in C++0x) are hash-maps (`unordered_(set|multiset|map|multiset)`). Some sketch or p-code would really help.

Comment: Just compare the "xxx mins ago" of your edit and of your comment that talks about your edit.

Comment: No, you're right in that I commented before I added the edit; my mistake. I was writing a comment and had the edit in my paste buffer, so I didn't think that the few seconds of gap would make a difference. I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: Actually it show 2 minutes of gap ;) But: Having no real answer yet but only comments seems like a good indicator that I am not the only one confused. Maybe write down some p-code in terms of standard-C++(-containers), then state why that doesn't cut and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I've added some pseudocase in case you're interested.

Comment: "I would like know whether the class dependencies and design policies I describe below are sound": in my experience, there are two things that nearly always indicate that you're doing something wrong, which you're going to regret further down the road: the first is *using a linked list data structure*, and the second is *implementing your own linked list. :)

Comment: Maybe I'm just slow, but even after all your edits, it's not quite clear what it is you're trying to achieve. Any chance you could describe just the goal, without getting bogged down in the *how*'s? What is it the data structure needs to support? (also, rather than appending one edit after the other, you could aid readability a lot by actually *editing* your post, instead of appending to it. We don't need to know how many times it has been edited, or precisely what was added each time. We just need to know what the question looks like *now*. :)

Comment: I rewrote the question to try to better explain what I was doing; hopefully it is more clear now. You're right -- it was a mess and hard to decipher after those additions. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `front()` should return a reference to a node containing the `value_type`

Sounds like your thinking of `begin` instead of `front`, in STL/Boost terms, except that `begin` methods usually return iterators instead of references.

> How would I be able to use a map of key hashes to `std::list::iterator` types and allow for addition of rows without having the entries in the map get outdated

Just do; "`list`s have the important property that insertion and splicing do not invalidate iterators to list elements, and that even removal invalidates only the iterators that point to the elements that are removed" ([STL docs](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html)).

If you wanted, you could maintain a single `std::list` for the entire table and a `vector` of iterators into it to represent the starting points of rows.

Besides, have you looked at [Boost.Intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/intrusive.html) and [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)? <del>And did you know that an `std::map` (red-black tree) of hashes is a very suboptimal way of representing a hash table?</del>

Comment: Ah, thanks for the quote; I didn't know that iterator positions are preserved in that way for std::list. Yes, I know that using an std::map is suboptimal, but the pseudocode was supposed to be a primitive sketch for description; I would have used boost::unordered_map if I were to go with the (bad) design. I'll be sure to look at Boost.Intrusive and Boost.MultiIndex; thanks!

Comment: Boost::Intrusive and Boost::MultiIndex seem to be very useful; I'm reading the documentation for both of them and will use them in the future. Thanks again for the help!